# Doubles in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make it so I can find people with a certain zipcode but list the results by their full name in ASC order under the users table...

```
  SELECT profiles.id 
    FROM `profiles`,`users` 
   WHERE profiles.zipcode = '$ZIPCODE' 
ORDER BY users.full_name ASC
```

It like shows doubles.

Comment: It like shows doubles? Could you form that into a question? And whats the error/problem?

Comment: it shows the id's twice like 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 55, 55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a join I think, try something like

```
SELECT Users.full_name
FROM Users
INNER JOIN profiles
ON profiles.user_id = users.id
WHERE profiles.zipcode = '$ZIPCODE' 
ORDER BY users.full_name ASC
```

I assume there is a foreign key for users in the profiles table?  The answer assumes a foreign key of user_id in the profiles table

EDIT:

A foreign key is a key belonging to another table.  So if you have a user and a profile table, you would most likely have a column in the profile table, that for each profile references a unique users (assuming users only have 1 profile each)

Comment: im trying to get a list of all the ids from profiles where the zipcode matches the one i put in, and orders the ids based off the full_name in users.

Comment: whats funny about the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show distinct IDs, then this will work (depending on your dialect of SQL, you may also be able to select distinct profiles.id and skip the group by statement).

```
   SELECT profiles.id 
   FROM (select * from `profiles`,`users` 
         WHERE profiles.zipcode = '$ZIPCODE' 
         ORDER BY users.full_name
         )subquery
   GROUP BY profiles.id;
```

Comment: That gets rid of double id's but doesn't order by full name

Answer (score 0):

In your query you're doing this:

```
FROM `profiles`,`users`
```

and not providing a `JOIN` or `WHERE` condition relative to the relationship of those tables. This is resulting in a cartesian product.  You're lucky you're only getting doubles; the result could easily be larger.